Movie or show in which a boy with a tape recorder meets an alien in the woods
In the film or show, a boy with a tape recorder meets an alien in the woods.



Proximity (2020)

A young NASA JPL scientist is abducted by extraterrestrials, but when no one believes his story he becomes obsessed with finding proof, which leads him on a journey of discovery.

The scene from which your snippet was taken occurs in the below video (at around 1 minute in)




Thank you! That was going to drive me nuts!
